# How can we use the Monotone Convergence Theorem $x_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1} + a/x_{n-1})$ for natural number $n$?

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

If we want to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that the sequence ${x_n}$ is convergent, we must show that:

1. ${x_n}$ is either monotone increasing and bounded above.
2. ${x_n}$ is either monotone decreasing and bounded below.

This is what I have so far:
$x_n - x_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1} + \frac{a}{x_{n-1}}) - x_{n-1} = \frac{a - {x_{n-1}}^2}{2x_{n-1}}$.

We can see from the above expression that the sequence is increasing when $x_{n-1} < \sqrt{2}$ and the sequence is decreasing when $x_{n-1} > \sqrt{2}$.
I have a feeling that the sequence is bounded by $\sqrt{2}$ and we will probably need to use subsequence? How should I continue?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you use \frac{}{} or \tfrac{}{} instead of using / for fractions? It is hard to read your question.

Comment: @LeeFisher Yes! Thank you for letting me know! I apologize for making it difficult to read.

Comment: By "Monotone Convergence Theorem" it seems you mean the result quoted.  **Not** the result with the same name in the theory of integration.

Comment: Do you mean $a=2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s talk about the simplest case of the question like
$$x_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}\right) \textrm{ for } n\in \mathbb{N} $$
where $x_0 $ and $ a$ are greater than $0$.
Then we are going to prove that the sequence $a_n$ is increasing and bounded below by $\sqrt a$.

Starting with a positive $x_0$, we have a positive sequence $x_n$. Then we can use H.M.$\ge $G.M. to get its lower bound as $$
x_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}\right) \geqslant \sqrt{x_{n-1} \cdot \frac{a}{x_{n-1}}}=\sqrt{a}
$$
Then use the idea of OP, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_n-x_{n-1} & =\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}\right)-x_{n-1} . \\
& =\frac{1}{2 x_{n-1}}\left(x_{n-1}^2+a-2 x ^2_{n-1}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2 x_{n-1}}\left(a-x ^2_{n-1}\right) \\
& \leqslant 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $x_n$ is monotonic decreasing and bounded below and hence is convergent.